# My phone keeps re-starting when I plug in charger

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace-2

Over the last couple of days my Galaxy Ace 2 (2.3.6) will not switch off while charging.

If I am not charging it will switch off, but the minute I plug the charger in it automatically switches itself on again.

If I take the battery out and replace it, the same thing happens when I plug the charger in. Diving mode is turned off.

Has anyone else had this? Does anyone one know how to cure it?